# cannot connect to database from zapier #1044 - Access denied for user

Tags: mysql

I am trying to connect Zapier to my Database. Zapier has very limited support for this and seem to be going round in circles.

I need to GRANT SELECT to a user on my database with this code;

```
GRANT SELECT ON my-database-here.my-table-here TO 'user-here'@'ip-address-here' IDENTIFIED BY 'my-password-here';
```

The error i receive is;

```
#1044 - Access denied for user 'xxx'@'localhost' to database 'xxxx'
```

The user has ALL PRIVILEGES but can't seem to get it to work. Any help here could be greatly received.

Thanks

Comment: You need to log in as a user with permissions. At least root should have been created when you installed MySQL

Answer (score 0):

You may need to set up a root account for your MySQL database:

In the terminal type:`mysqladmin -u root password 'root password goes here'`

And then to invoke the MySQL client:`mysql -h localhost -u root -p`

you have 2 issues:

1 => `mysql -uroot -p` should be typed in bash (also known as your terminal) not in MySQL 
     command-line.    You fix this error by typing.

```
 exit
```

in your MySQL command-line. Now you are back in your bash/terminal command-line.

You have a syntax error:

```
mysql -uroot -p;
```

the semicolon in front of -p needs to go. The correct syntax is:

```
mysql -uroot -p
```

type the correct syntax in your bash commandline. Enter a password if you have one set up; else just hit the enter button. You should get a response that is similar to this:

[image]

Comment: mysqladmin -u root password 'root password goes here'  Is this Syntax correct??  Just bashes out an error

Comment: you should run mysql -u root -p in bash, not at the MySQL command-line. If you are in mysql, you can exit by typing exit.

Comment: You need to log in as root—e.g., by running mysql -u root -p. Then you'll have full permissions on the database server, and you can create other users

Comment: OK, i am in phpMyAdmin console, i am running these cmd from SQL tab. Is this the correct place??

Comment: where do i access the terminal on my hosing server?